# UIWebView loadRequest when applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

In my app from applicationDidEnterBackground i want to ask the application for more time to

create a UIWebView and load request  with UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier, then in the delegate

method of UIWebView (webViewDidFinishLoad) i want to do a stuff there and show an alert or

notification while the

application is still reining in the background .

so how i can do that?.

Comment: you want to show alert once the background task(loading page) is complete?

Comment: yes @Ravin this is what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's documentation for [`UIApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes%3a) class for `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`: method says:

> You can call this method at any point in your application’s execution.
>   You may also call this method multiple times to mark the beginning of
>   several background tasks that run in parallel. However, each task must
>   be ended separately. You identify a given task using the value
>   returned by this method.
>
> **This method can be safely called on a non-main thread.**

So, once web view finish loading in background you can trigger another operation from `webViewDidFinishLoad` to show alert.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive `applicationDidEneterBackground` your app is already effectively in the background. At that moment all your networking should be closed and you really shouldn't try to show any alerts or notifications.